# Angular v1 Multi-Checkbox Validation

Tags: angularjs, validation, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to ensure that at least one checkobx is ticked, I'm using a directive to validate the input when the form is submitted.

My mark-up for the checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="payment_types[]" ng-model="payment_types[1]"
       value="1" id="payment-types-ids-1" 
       required>Payment Method 1</label>
```

I am using CakePHP3's form helpers to render the inputs so I don't have control over the "name" attribute which the helper renders with the brackets:

```
name="payment_types[]"
```

This seems to cause problem as the console of this plunker reports:

https://plnkr.co/edit/0rPOGvVvPRACthn1AbXc?p=preview

I am trying to ensure/catch at last one checkobox selection, but the directive only catches the invalid email. So without using ng-repeat how can I validate multicheckbox selections?

Comment: The square brackets `[]` in the name attribute `name="payment_types[]"`  is likely causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : payment_types.length == 0}">
<label>
 <input type="checkbox" name="payment_types[]" ng-model="payment_types[1]"
        value="1" id="payment-types-ids-1"
        required="required">Payment Method 1
</label>
</div> <br/>
```

So if some one has not selected at least on payment_types, the length will  be zero and your this form property will be in error status. So button will not enable.

Comment: thanks but that doesn't work: https://plnkr.co/edit/hGUnxpKdrEO6fezXw1An?p=preview